# I want to insert data into the DB automatically after filled a row in datagridview

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2016

I bound my `DataGridView` with a DataBase file. I want to save each and every row to the database after I finish entering values into that row.

I know how to save the complete table but not every row.

The single row that I enter, I want it to save automatically to the DB after I enter a value in last cell of that row and move to the next row.

I wrote some code but not saving but displaying message "record Saved".
Blow my code

```
    private void dataGridView1_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.ColumnIndex == 5)
        {

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("insert into invtempdb (fullname, quantity, itmbyp, itmprimary, itmtotal) values( '" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1] + "', '" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2] + "','" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3] + "','" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4] + "','" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5] + "')", con);
            MessageBox.Show("value saved");
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
```

Comment: @ mar_s I am using sql2016

Comment: @ mar_s Is there any possibility of my current row last column that query execute

Answer (score 0):

Okay, from what I've understood of your question, you need to update the database as soon as you complete filling a row.

You can do that in this way:

The `DataGridView` has many different events available for usage:

- `RowLeave`
- `RowsAdded`
- `RowsRemoved`

And many more, I think for your exact requirement these three events should be enough.

What you've to do is, put the sql command to update the DataBase inside the event `RowLeave`. This will update the DataBase everytime you leave the last cell of a particular row.

Read more about the events in their descriptions to find the best suitor for your purpose, but, this is the way to proceed further.

Extension:

I can't see where you've used the `RowLeave` event, but here's a solution.

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection string); //put your connection string there
    SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand("insert into invtempdb (fullname, quantity, itmbyp, itmprimary, itmtotal) values(@a,@b,@c,@d,@e);", con)

    insert.Parameters.Add("@a",dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1] );
    insert.Parameters.Add("@b",dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2] );
    insert.Parameters.Add("@c",dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3] );
    insert.Parameters.Add("@d",dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4] );
    insert.Parameters.Add("@e",dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5] );
    insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Put this code inside your event and you're good to go. Your basics are very weak, focus on that else you'll always be stuck on very small errors.

Comment: @ Shardul I did what you told. But not Saving into databse file but message showing that data saved. maybe my be some error in my code.So Just take a look and tell me where i did wrong.  SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("insert into invtempdb (fullname, quantity, itmbyp, itmprimary, itmtotal) values( '" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1] + "', '" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2] + "','" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3] + "','" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4] + "','" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5] + "')", con);
                MessageBox.Show("value saved");

Comment: @vijay I can't make sense of your code here, please edit your question and paste this code into your question after giving 4 spaces for indentation.

Comment: @vijay Check it out.

Comment: @ shardul that total code i wrote under  private void dataGridView1_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)

Comment: @vijay Dont put the code in `RowLeave`, cause once you leave the row, the property, `DataGridView.CurrentRow` won't return what you need. Use `UserAddedRow` event instead.

Comment: I Put the code there but one error is coming when i pasted the code there.Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
"Error CS1061 'DataGridViewRowEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'ColumnIndex' and no extension method 'ColumnIndex' accepting a first argument of type 'DataGridViewRowEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) purchase D:\Projects\Practise\Purch\purchase\purchase\Form6.cs 49 Active"

Comment: Some one help me i stuck there

Comment: @vijay try replacing `dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1]` with `dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["fullname"]   Do this for all 5 columns and try executing.

Comment: @ shardul. I did. but one error is coming. Column named fullname cannot be found. Parameter name column Name. I checked my database file also. Field names are same.

Comment: @vijay okay then do this where you first initiate the datagridview   dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Value = "fullname";   for all the columns. You can keep whatever header value you want for the column. Later on inside the SQL update command you can refer to the column by using the headers you set yourself.

Comment: @ shardul i figurared it out in some way so it is working now.Thanks for your support. I read the value of that and stored in one varialbe and i saved that."string value = Convert.ToString((dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1] as DataGridViewTextBoxCell).Value);"